# Entity Framework with mySQL problems - asnotracking and include table numbers

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm testing an ASP.NET application that runs with the Entity Framework on SQL Server, and I'm having the following problem.

According to the code below, the following error is displayed: "String was not recognized as valid Boolean";

```
var data = DataContext.TableName
    .Include("Table2")
    .Include("Table2.Table3")
    .Include("Table4")
    .Include("Table5")
    .Include("Table5.Table6")
    .Include("Table7")
    .Where(x => x.Id == 10)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Versions:

- .NET Framework: 4.5.2
- Entity Framework: 6.2.0
- MySql.Data: 8.0.11
- MySql.Data.EntityFramework: 8.0.11
- mySQL: 8.0

When I run the same code with the Entity Framework in SQL Server, the problem does not occur.

Does anyone know if it's a limitation of Entity Framework with mySQL?